# htaccess folder override into sub folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to provide a short URL in specific system. This short URL should be override into sub folder in same system.

User URL

```
https://go.store.com/t/abc
```

Need to be work as

```
https://go.store.com/compat.php?property=abc
```

My htaccess code is

```
RewriteRule ^t/([\w-]+)$ compat.php?property=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This is not working as expected. All server configurations related to htaccess is done and can you help to do this success.

---

Used this code part and then $_GET['property'] = t\abc. Need to get only abc value.

```
RewriteRule ^(t\/\w+)/?$ compat.php?property=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Your regex needs to be something like `t\/\w+`

Comment: Do it and then property value is passed as t/abc

Comment: `RewriteRule ^t/([\w-]+)/?$ compat.php?property=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` should work fine.

Comment: yes. similar code just work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me

```
 RewriteRule ^t/(\w+)?$ compat.php?property=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Now

```
https://go.store.com/t/abc will be redirected to https://go.store.com/compat.php?property=abc
```

Thanks @anubhava for help

Comment: You can accept your own answer as correct one, saying thanks to @anubhava :)